# Ionic-android: como obtener fecha y hora por GPS? (no del sistema)

Tags: android, angularjs-2.0, cordova, ionic2

el problema real que aun no resuelvo es como evitar que la app que estoy desarrollando me guarde una hora que no es la oficial del pais/localidad donde me encuentro

el timestamp que retorna ionic-native/geolocation es el del sistema, asi que no me sirve

utilizé el plugin cordova-plugin-advanced-geolocation que me retona el timestamp por gps pero me congela la app, ademas solo funciona para android 5.0 - 6.x

pd: la solucion debe funcionar incluso sin conexion a internet

cualquier ayuda de verdad la agradezco!

Comment: Creo que no es posible, al menos, deberías de alguna forma obtener el fichero RINEX de observación, http://www.gage.es/sites/default/files/gLAB/HTML/Observation_Rinex_v2.11.html y obtener la hora de ahí. También puedes mirar las utilidades de JavaScript para obtener la hora según to localidad. Por ejemplo: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString

Comment: qué uso quieres darle al timestamp? por qué no puede definir la hora el servidor cuando vayas a guardar el valor? Puedes obtener la fecha y hora de algún servidor NTP, claro que necesitas Internet. Si utilizas la api de Google para obtener la ubicación, dentro del objeto tienes un método gettime puedes mirar cómo funciona sin Internet. Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

La API de Google Maps tiene la opción de calcular la hora local por medio de enviar la hubicación actual.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/intro

Según la información proporcionada por Google se puede obtener la hora local de la siguiente forma:
[image]

Comment: la documentacion creo que esta un poco ambigüa o no llego a entenderla del todo (si lo que quiero es el timestamp, por qué debo pasarselo por parametro?)... aun asi, requiere estar conectado a internet por lo que veo